# How to add an initial access key for account

Tags: nearprotocol

Suppose I want to add an initial access key for a new account. `CreateAccountAction` requires `receiver_id` to be the ID of the new account. `AddKeyAction` requires `receiver_id` = `signer_id`. How it's possible to have `CreateAccountAction` and `AddKeyAction` in the same transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use a special permission which we call `actor_id`. When a new account is created using `CreateAccount`, all subsequent actions use `actor_id == receiver_id`. This is the cause until you execute `DeleteAccount` action, which changes `actor_id` back to `predecessor_id`.